# How to insert in a table with foreach

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, mysqli

I need to insert the searched results into a table
i already done with getting the names of any value but its hard for me to INSERT them in the table.
here is some code:

```
    <?php


$con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "library");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

  //var_dump($_POST['genre']);
  $genres = $_POST['genre'];



  foreach ($genres as $k=>$v){

   $rslt="INSERT INTO 'history'(id,name) 
       VALUES('NULL', '".$k."')";

  }
```

Comment: `$rslt` is just a string, are you actually running that SQL query anyqhere ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your id column is auto-increment you should not put NULL between quotes. 
(That would mean you're inserting the string 'NULL' wich is not NULL).

You can find [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html) the doc about inserting rows with an auto_increment value.

Try like this :

```
"INSERT INTO 'history'(id,name) VALUES(NULL, '".$k."')";
```

or this also works :

```
"INSERT INTO 'history'(name) VALUES('".$k."')";
```